# Using PDO to display the current users name

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use PDO and $_SESSION['uid'] to be able to grab the current members name and display it back.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`uid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`salt` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`birthday` date NOT NULL,
`activation` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Above is table

```
<?php
require ('common.php'); // Database connection, Session Starter 
$ps = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid = :uid");
$ps->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['uid'];, PDO::PARAM_STR, 0);
$ps->execute();
$ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($ps as $row)
{
echo $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Above shows a blank screen.

```
 <?php 
 session_start(); 
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
 var_dump($_SESSION);
 ?>
```

Print_R shows Array ( [uid] => Array ) 
Var_dump shows array(1) { ["uid"]=> string(5) "Array" }

```
<?php 
require("common.php"); 

if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
$query = "SELECT uid, email, password, salt FROM users WHERE  email = :email";  
$query_params = array( ':email' => $_POST['email'] ); 

try { 
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) { die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 

$login_ok = false; 
$row = $stmt->fetch(); 
if($row) 
{ 
$check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
for($round = 0; $round < 222222; $round++) 
{ 
$check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
} 

if($check_password === $row['password']) 
{  
$login_ok = true; 
} 
} 

if($login_ok) 
{  
unset($row['salt']); 
unset($row['password']); 
$_SESSION['uid'] = $row; 
header("Location: https://**"); 
die("Redirecting to: https://**"); 
} 
else 
{  
header("Location: https://**"); 
die("Redirecting to: https://**"); 
} 
} 
?>
```

included login.php

Comment: you have a typo in your **bindParam**:

use this 

    `$ps->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['uid'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 0);`

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian tried that still no change with the script.

Comment: show the contents of $_SESSION; try var_dump or print_r and update its content in question

Comment: Your code obviously has a bug, because your `uid` in the session is a **STRING**, containing the word `Array`. if it was actually an array, you'd have gotten a dump of an array's contents, or at least an empty array. That means you've build your session incorrectly in the first place. You're literally trying to do `WHERE uid = 'Array'`.

Comment: `$stmt->fetch()` always returns an array, which you assign into the session. You're then using that array in yhour bind() call and forcing PHP to treat it as a string, so the actual array gets trashed and turned into the WORD `Array`. You need to bind `$_SESSION['uid']['uid']` instead.

Comment: @MarcB I used $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid']; to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
       $ps->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['uid'];, PDO::PARAM_STR, 0);
```

with

```
       $ps->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['uid'];, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12); //12 means length of the data type
```

Comment: I tried that removed the semicolon from $_SESSION['uid']; still not displaying any data.